# select different MAX(values) depending on array

Tags: php, database, sqlite

I want to select different MAX(values) of different sensornodes. My Problem is that the WHERE...IN... clause works like many logical "OR", but I need  the MAX($measure) from each sensornode. I know how to do it with a loop, but I think there is a better solution to do this.

This is the table 'measurement' of the database:

```
ID          humidity    temperature  date        time        sensornode
----------  ----------  -----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           22.00%      18.00C       06/03/2017  13:07:18    WSN1      
2           22.00%      18.00C       06/03/2017  13:08:19    WSN2      
3           34.00%      21.00C       06/03/2017  13:09:19    WSN3      
4           21.00%      20.00C       06/03/2017  13:10:19    WSN4
```

The query should be somthing like this

```
$measure //is either 'temperature' or 'humidity', depends on the users input.
$sensornode // is a string which is converted with the implode-function from an array which includes the selected 'sensornodes' of the users input
$sql_query = "SELECT MAX($measure) AS $measure 
    FROM measurement 
    WHERE sensornode IN ('$sensornode')"; 
$data = executeQuery($sql_query, $measure);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the maximum value for each sensor node, use grouping:

```sql
SELECT sensornode,
       max(temperature)
FROM measurement
GROUP BY sensornode;
```

To restrict that to certain sensor nodes, just add a WHERE:

```sql
SELECT sensornode,
       max(temperature)
FROM measurement
WHERE sensornode IN ('WSN1', 'WSN2', ...)
GROUP BY sensornode;
```